# Objective-C operator precedence of square brackets used as message expression/notation?

Tags: objective-c

Does the Objective-C message expression (message notation) operator, which uses square brackets [], have the same precedence as the C operator for array subscripting, which also uses square brackets []?

I refer to [this table of C operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence).

Also, an analogous question applies to the Objective-C "dot syntax" operator for accessor method invocation compared to the C operator for "element selection by reference". Do they have the same precedence?

I searched for an hour for a straightforward, definitive answer to this basic question. Surprisingly, I did not find one. Hence, this question. Links welcome.

Comment: There's no ObjC language spec (that's public, anyways), so there won't be any written documentation for this; the answer is whatever the compiler does.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to know this, by the way?

Comment: The message send syntax isn't an operator to begin with, so trying to place it on the table of operators is nonsensical.

Comment: @KevinBallard: Function invocation is considered an "operator". Why wouldn't a message send be?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Because syntax? That's like asking why using parens as a group isn't an operator. Or why the quote character isn't an operator.

Comment: @KevinBallard: Right, sure, they don't acutually operate, but they have to have a priority when they're parsed. I just meant that invocation has a place on the precendence table. A parenthetical grouping takes precendence over anything else. I see what you mean, that it's strictly outside the table, but if the same is true for square brackets, then that's the answer to the question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell On another question about operator precedence, one person wrote to just use parens, another wrote in response he doesn't like excess parens, learn operators. I can sympathize with latter sentiment. So I want back to a recent statement where I used parens because I wasn't sure of operator precedence. And that started me down a rabbit hole to asking this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have become confused because many explanations of grammars and precedence take the shortcut of saying that operators have precedence.  They don't.  It is productions in the grammar that have precedence, and they have precedence relative to other productions.  It is only meaningful for two productions to have precedence relative to each other if the grammar is ambiguous (meaning it can produce two different parse trees for the same input), and if the ambiguity is resolved by specifying the precedence of one production over the other.

Let me explain with an example.

Here's a toy grammar:

```
expression =
    | IDENTIFIER
    | NUMBER
    | expression '+' expression
    | expression '*' expression
    | expression '(' expression ')' // function call
    | '(' expression ')' // grouping
    | expression '[' expression ']' // array subscript
    | '[' expression IDENTIFIER ':' expression ']' // message send
    ;
```

Now, consider parsing `1 + 2 * 3` with this grammar.  There are two valid parse trees:

```
  +              *
 / \            / \
1   *          +   3
   / \        / \
  2   3      1   2
```

By specifying that the `*` production has a higher precedence than the `+` production, we require the parser to produce the left tree instead of the right tree.  Thus the idea of a precedence relationship between the `+` production and the `*` production makes sense: it has an effect on the parser's output.

Similarly, `1 + foo(3)` has two parse trees:

```
  +               ()
 / \             /  \
1   ()          +    3
   /  \        / \
 foo   3      1  foo
```

So again the idea of a precedence relationship between the '+' production and the function call production makes sense.  The case of `1 + foo[3]` (which uses the subscript production in place of the function call production) is analogous, so it makes sense to specify a precedence relationship between the '+' production and the subscript production.

Now consider `1 + (2 * 3)`.  The grammar can only produce one possible parse tree:

```
  +
 / \
1  ( )
    |
    *
   / \
  2   3
```

There is no need for a precedence relationship between the `+` production and the grouping production, because there is only one way to parse this input.  It would be meaningless to specify that the grouping production has higher precedence than the `+` production, because there is no other parse tree that you could produce by doing so.

Finally, consider `1 + [2 add:3]`.  This is analogous to the grouping example.  There is only one possible parse tree:

```
   +
  / \
 /   \
1   [ ]
   / | \
  /  |  \
 2  add  3
```

No other parse tree is possible.  There is no need to specify a precedence relationship between the `+` production and the message send production.  Specifying a precedence relationship between them would have no effect, because the grammar simply doesn't allow this input to be parsed any other way.

Comment: I was afraid someone who knew the science of computing, compiler design and parsing would come along and explain why my question was nonsensical. Your answer is totally worth the anguish of facing my fears.

Comment: @robmayoff superb explanation. thanx

Answer (score 1):

They are in the same precedence group. I believe the message send [] is equivalent to () because the runtime treats them as parenthesis in the case of messages.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Operator_Precedence

Comment: I did find that Techotopia page, but that site is so spammy, I didn't trust the information.